# Counter how many errors were triggered in PHP

Tags: php, error-handling

If I have to call to a third-party legacy function that doesn't allow proper error checking,
is there a global counter on how many error-notices were already triggered by a php script?

I would like to detect in my script if there were errors/warnings/notices during a function call triggered and react accordingly in my script.

As a workaround, I would go for counting the number of rows in the apache errorlog before and after the function call, but that doesn't work:

```
<?php
$errorlogsize_before=filesize(DEBUGMODE_LOGFILE);
third_party_function();
$errorlogsize_after=filesize(DEBUGMODE_LOGFILE);
echo "Logsize before:".$errorlogsize_before."; Logsize after:".$errorlogsize_after."
```

They display the same filesize.

Comment: Not by default. You can count them yourself, or just check the logs.

Comment: Why the downvote? I clarified the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll assume your use case is a call to a third-party legacy function that doesn't allow proper error checking. In that case, you can change the error handler temporarily with [set_error_handler()](http://php.net/set_error_handler) and restore it afterwards with [restore_error_handler()](http://php.net/restore_error_handler). Other alternatives like [error_get_last()](http://php.net/error_get_last) discard all errors but the last one.

Answer (score 2):

You can use function `set_error_handler` and implement your own counters

For example: I use custom error handler to send UDP data to statsd daemon when PHP error occurs. Then you can graph errors by type and by page/file

Comment: Please provide some clarified info in the future. This is no help.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own counter:

```
<?php
$counter = 0;
$site = "://testsite.hjkh/"; //<== IncorrectSite
 fopen($site,"r")
 or die(errorCount + 1); //<==ErrorCount +1
 ?>
```

At the end of your script, Echo the ErrorCount.
 Take a look here: http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_misc_die.asp